# How to make one function instead of 16 - by adding a string?

Tags: jquery

I have many items on my page, and each item has a text.
By clicking the item, the text for that item shows.

I stored all items in a variable:

```
var itemImages = $( '.foo, .bar, .foobar');
```

The texts has the same names as the items + -text. I stored the text in a variable too:

```
var objectTexts = $( '.foo-text, .bar-text, .foobar-text' );
```

I made the functions like this:

```
 $('.foo').click(function(){
    $( objectTexts ).hide();
    $('.foo-text').fadeIn('fast');
 });

 $('.bar').click(function(){
    $( objectTexts ).hide();
    $('.bar-text').fadeIn('fast');
 });

 $('.foobar').click(function(){
    $( objectTexts ).hide();
    $('.foobar-text').fadeIn('fast');
 });
```

But instead of making 16 different functions, I would like to have only one; something like this:

```
 $(itemImages).click(function(){
    $( objectTexts ).hide();
    $(itemImages + ('-text')).fadeIn('fast');
 });
```

But how?

Edit: The items (itemImages) also get an extra class when clicked: .moved 
This is to show css animation.

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Like this `$(itemImages).click(function(){$( objectTexts ).hide();
    $($(this).attr("class")+ ('-text'))).fadeIn('fast');
 });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the items only have one class name, you can create the classname for the text from that:

```
itemImages.click(function(){
  objectTexts.hide();
  $('.' + $(this).attr('class') + '-text')).fadeIn('fast');
});
```

(The variables `itemImages` and `objectTexts` are already jQuery objects, so you don't need to wrap them in `$()` when you use them.)

Comment: this not work for case when class attribute like: `class="foo someclass1"`

Comment: The item (.foo) gets an extra class when clicked: .moved 
Is that why this doesn't work? When I use the inspector in Chrome, I can see that the text is there, but it is not visible...

Comment: @Grundy: That's exactly why I started the answer with excluding that case.

Comment: :-D somehow I missed this

Comment: @kaTon: Yes, that would get you a selector like `'.foo moved-text'` or `.moved foo-text`. If that is the only other class that can be there, you can filter that out; in place of `$(this).attr('class')` you can use `$.trim($(this).attr('class').replace('moved', ''))`.

Answer (score 3):

Generic classes and search within the DOM object you click. Add a .clickable class to anything you want to target, and a .text class to all items of text. You can place multiple classes on any DOM item. **This assumes the text is a child of the item you click.**

```
 $('.clickable').click(function(){
    //hide all text
    $('.text').hide();
    $(this).find('.text').fadeIn('fast');
 });
```

or as I prefer:

```
$(document)
    .on('click', '.clickable', function(){
        //hide all text
        $('.text').hide();
        //Show only .text that is a child of what you clicked.
        $(this).find('.text').fadeIn('fast');
     })
;
```

If you want the displayable items to be non children DOM elements, its best to use IDs to associate between them. Example code here: http://jsfiddle.net/tx19keze/3/

Comment: Partly works, but I have 4 languages for each text, so each text has a class. With this solution, all 4 languages are showing on top of each other...

Comment: This may show you it working better with your goal used as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/tx19keze/5/

Comment: Fantastic! But I'll have to add id's to all the items and all the texts – now they only have classes...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
 itemImages .click(function(){
      objectTexts.hide();
      var currentClass = $(this).attr("class");
      $("."+currentClass+"-text")).fadeIn('fast');
 });
```

Comment: this not work for case when class attribute like: `class="foo someclass1"`

Comment: The item (.foo) gets an extra class when clicked: .moved Is that why this doesn't work? When I use the inspector in Chrome, I can see that the text is there, but it is not visible...

Answer (score 1):

Put a data attribute on your image tags and use that to display your text

```
<img src="img-src" data-text="foo-text" />
```

Put an ID on the div's holding your text that matches your data-text on your img tag. And add an objectText class you can use to hide them.

```
<div id="foo-text" class="objectText"> ... some text here ... </div>
```

Then your javascript would be:

```
$('img').click(function(){
    var text = $(this).data('text');
    $('.objectText').hide();
    $('#' + text).show('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `this` to get the class name of clicked element and then select the required element to hide/display

http://jsfiddle.net/qfafby54/

```
$( '.foo, .bar, .foobar').click(function(){
    console.log("." + $(this).attr("class"));
    $("." + $(this).attr("class")+ "-text").fadeIn('fast')
})
```

This method won't work of you have multiple classes for same element. In that case you can try something like

**HTML**

```
<div class="foo" data-show="foo-text">FOO</div>
<div class="bar" data-show="bar-text">bar</div>

<div class="foo-text">Foo Text</div>
<div class="bar-text">bar text</div>
```

**JS**
    $( '.foo, .bar, .foobar').click(function(){
        $("." + $(this).data("show")).fadeIn('fast')
    })

http://jsfiddle.net/qfafby54/1/

Even better approach is to make your class names generic and handle event on them.

Comment: yes as `cngodles` rightly pointed out use this only if `there is only one class on the item` else you may add it (class name to hide/show) to data attribute within the element and get the same on click. Best approach would be to make your class names generic.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variant, a bit change structure, and check what class has clicked element.

Something like this

```
var items = ['foo','bar','foobar'];
var itemImages = $( items.map(function(el){return '.'+el}).join(',') );

var objectTexts = $( items.map(function(el){return '.'+el+'-text'}).join(',') );

itemImages.click(function(){
    $( objectTexts ).hide();
    var $this = $(this);
    for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){//loop over classes
        if($this.hasClass(items[i])){//check that clicked element has current class
            $('.'+items[i]+'-text').fadeIn('fast');
            return;
        }
    }
});
```